# Nested SQL in a ORDER BY Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue in resolving a specific case with SQL.

I have two tables - **Module** and **Exam** - with the following 
structures.

**Module**

- Module code
- Module name

**Exam**

- Student ID
- Module code

I would like to fetch in a DECREASING ORDER of popularity the Module.
Popularity is given by the occurence of exams for the given module.

I want to use a nested query within a ORDER BY clause but I'm not sure about it.

EDIT :

Data sample

```
Module Name | Module Code
---------------------------------
Programming | CS118
Database    | CS230
Finance     | IB143
Geometry    | MA109



Student Id | Module Code
----------------------------------
1323       | CS118
1432       | CS118
1956       | CS118
1323       | CS230
1956       | CS230
1432       | MA109
1751       | IB143
```

Given this sample, what I expect to get is

```
Programming
Database
Finance
Geometry
```

My RDBMS is Oracle.

Comment: what is your rdbms? can you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Add some sample table data to show us the wanted order (as well formatted text, click `{}`.) Also show us your query attempt.

Comment: So you want to order by the count(1) of exams for a module?  this could be accomplished via an inline view or a window function (if supported)

Comment: I've edited my post, proving sample and expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple join with group by & order by should do the trick

```sql
select m."Module name"
from Module m
left join Exam e
  on (m."Module code" = e."Module code")
group by m."Module name"
order by count(*) desc, m."Module name";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inline view to get the counts then order by it.

This should be fairly database agnostic.

```
SELECT M.moduleCode, M.Modulename, B.cnt
FROM Module M
INNER JOIN (Select count(1) cnt, ModuleCode from exam group by ModuleCode) B
  on M.ModuleCode= B.ModuleCode
ORDER BY B.Cnt Desc
```

Comment: This query works fine! Could you just explain me why though? That would really help my understanding :)

Comment: lukStorms answer is simpler and also accurate.  I was getting a count of each of each exam grouped by the module code then joining back to order.  LueStorms answer avoids the subquery

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one and I will explain the logic:

```
SELECT module.name
FROM module
INNER JOIN exam ON module.module_code = exam.module_code
GROUP BY module.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You want to SELECT the module name so that goes in the first line. Then you specify where to find the name. For this query, we want to join together the module and exam tables because there is relevant information in both. You can join them using the module code field.

At this point, your joined table looks exactly like your exam table but also includes the module name (and another module code column from the module table). The group by statement compresses the table based on the field you specify, in this case the module name. The COUNT(*) function counts the number of records associated with each name and we can ORDER based on that.